# Problem trying to install jhbuild (for PyGObject)

Tags: git-bash, mingw-w64, pygobject, failed-installation, jhbuild

I'm trying to install PyGObject,  so (I guess) I need to install jhbuild. I was following the tutorial that I found on https://developer.gnome.org/jhbuild/unstable/getting-started.html.pt_BR (I got there following the links on Python documentation, so it's probably the official installation guide)

I created a folder called jhbuild inside my user, and a folder called checkout, inside the folder jhbuild, and started a git bash there.

I ran `cd jhbuild`, `./autogen.sh`

Then the message *`make' is required to configure & build jhbuild*

I continued the tutorial anyway with `make`, but the message *bash: make: command not found appeared*

What do I have to do to continuing the installation?

Comment: jhbuild has nothing to do with installing pygobject in your system, you can easily do that using the package manager of your distro (on linux) or MSYS2 (on windows). Also if you son't know what "make" is, I'm afraid you will have to do some more researches on the linux system, its components and of course what is make itself and jhbuild

Comment: Well, I'm using Windows... in fact I don't have any knowledge about Linux.  But thank you! I'll try to use MSYS2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error `bash: make: command not found` indicates you don't have make on your system or in your `PATH`.
You should install `make` on your system. How depends on your operating system.

It has nothing to do with jhbuild per se.

In fact I'm building PyGobject in my MSYS2+MinGW-w64 environment completely without jhbuild, using meson and ninja.

If you're a beginner and you're on Windows the easiest way to get PyGObject  is to use [MSYS2](https://www.msys2.org/) and install the mingw-w64-x86_64-python-gobject package (with `pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-python-gobject`).

Comment: You should add to your answer that jhbuild has nothing to do with installing pygobject

Comment: @gianmt Ok, I added it.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, but I've just started programing... what do I need to use PyGObject and how can I install that?

Comment: I have updated my answer above. As the others have already said: you should use MSYS2.